# PHP API not working in REST implementation

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, rest

I am trying to build a simple RESTful API using PHP. The request works with a normal query in the URL path, however, I am getting a "404 URL not found" error when implementing REST approach

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z|_-]*)$ index.php?name=$1 [nc,qsa]
```

index.php (snippet)

```
// process client request (via URL)
header("Content-Type:application/json");
include('functions.php');
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){

    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $result=get_items_by_category("$name");

    if(empty($result)){
      print($name);
      deliver_response(200,"Duh, gee, Mort, there's nothing here!",NULL);

      }else{
      deliver_response(200,"Hit the road,Jack!",$result);
      }

  }else{

  deliver_response(400,"This is not the request you're looking for",NULL);

}
```

Comment: What is the  URL you are sending that is causing 404?

Comment: I would prefer using [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) framework

Comment: I did some more debugging, and I found out that /api/Grill(my) does not work, maybe due to parentheses in the name? Because /api/Pasta works

Comment: There are no parentheses in the regex so yeah it won't match that.
What is your plan for URL syntax? can help you with a regex to get it to work.

Comment: ah yes, forgot about that. Will take a look at slim framework too.

Comment: turned that into an answer, as i don't think you'll get a better one unfortunately without more information - if you need any more help drop it in comments and I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: I would go with a more standard `^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [qsa]` - this will just match everything then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote:

```
I did some more debugging, and I found out that /api/Grill(my) does not work, 
maybe due to parentheses in the name? Because /api/Pasta works
```

There are no parentheses in the regex so yeah it won't match that.

What is your plan for URL syntax? can help you with a regex to get it to work.

Comment: well, right now I am trying to get the regex to give me multiple variables:
RewriteRule ^additem/(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*$ additem.php?name=$1&desc=$2&price=$3&isVeg=$4&isHot=$5&isNuts=$6&isGluten=$7&thumb=$8&cat=$9

Is there a way to get this working, or better alternative to this?

Comment: the . character will match everything, including forward slashes which is going to mess up how it reads the url if anyone puts one in, or possibly just the /'s that are in there anyway.
I would specify actual character sets for each section of the URL, otherwise no there's not really a nicer alternative to it afaik

Comment: Yepp, ended up using ([0-9A-Za-z]+) for strings and ([0-9]+) for numbers, worked like a charm. My bad for not consulting any reading material beforehand.